Remote Redis Pub/Sub Partial Base64 encoded Data Flutter
I am trying to do this:
Video=> Python app turns into Frames => publishes it, as base64 encoded frames to Redis => Flutter Subscribes to Redis, Decodes and Shows it.
Testing this with localhost redis and it works fine, but at remote redis server. It is giving me partial base64 data after subscribing to it, which flutter isnt accepting.
flutter: Error decoding base64 string: FormatException: Invalid length, must be multiple of four (at character 10036) ...LHr0Jr7z+BX7UfwP/am0eW28H6ujXsEQ/tPQdQQC4gyOjJyHX/aHFen9drUnG0tE00uzW33HHVw
Tested with a Python SUB app, it works fine.
This is my Python Code to publish the frames
import redis
import base64
import cv2


def publish_frames(video_path, channel_name, redis_host='non-localhost-ip', redis_port=6380):
    # Connect to Redis server
    client = redis.StrictRedis(host=redis_host, port=redis_port, decode_responses=True, db=0)

    # Open the video file
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

    if not cap.isOpened():
        print(f"Error: Could not open video file {video_path}")
        return

    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break

        try:
            print("Frames")
            # Encode the frame as a JPEG image
            _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)

            # Convert the image buffer to a base64 string
            frame_base64 = base64.b64encode(buffer).decode('utf-8')

            # Ensure proper base64 padding (this should not be necessary in Python, but it's good to ensure)
            # if len(frame_base64) % 4 != 0:
            #     frame_base64 += '=' * (4 - len(frame_base64) % 4)

            # Publish the base64 string to the Redis channel
            client.publish(channel_name, frame_base64)
            cv2.waitKey(1)  # Adjust this delay as needed (e.g., 1 ms for high frame rate)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error encoding or publishing frame: {e}")

        # Delay to simulate the video frame rate


    cap.release()
    print(f"Finished publishing frames from {video_path}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_path = 'videoplayback.mp4'
    channel_name = 'video_frames'
    publish_frames(video_path, channel_name)

This is the Flutter Code to receieve the frames:
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ioredis/ioredis.dart';

void main() async {
  final redis = Redis(RedisOptions(host: 'non-localhost-ip', port: 6380));
  print('Connected to Redis');

  runApp(MyApp(redis: redis));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Redis redis;

  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.redis}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Redis Video Stream',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: VideoStreamPage(redis: redis),
    );
  }
}

class VideoStreamPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Redis redis;

  const VideoStreamPage({Key? key, required this.redis}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoStreamPageState createState() => _VideoStreamPageState();
}

class _VideoStreamPageState extends State<VideoStreamPage> {
  List<Uint8List> frames = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startListening();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    stopListening();
  }

  void startListening() async {
    try {
      print('Subscribing to video_frames...');
      RedisSubscriber subscriber = await widget.redis.subscribe('video_frames');
      print('Subscribed to video_frames');

      subscriber.onMessage = (String channel, String? message) async {
        if (message != null) {
          print('Received message: ${message.substring(0, 30)}...');  // Print start of the base64 string
          try {
            Uint8List bytes = base64.decode(message);
            print('Frame decoded successfully.');
            setState(() {
              frames.add(bytes);
            });
          } catch (e) {
            print('Error decoding base64 string: $e');
          }
        }
      };
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    }
  }

  void stopListening() async {
    await widget.redis.disconnect();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Video Stream'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: frames.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Image.memory(
            frames[index],
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

Thanks for any help and guidance. I am new to flutter and struggling!
